# Borders look so close on phone

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I have created a headline with the following HTML:

```css
.menu-item-text-mobile {
    -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    transition: border 200ms ease-out;
    border-bottom: 2.11px solid transparent;
    border-top: 2.11px solid transparent;
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;

}

.menu-item-text-mobile:focus {
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;

}

.menu-item-text-mobile::after {
    bottom: 1px;
}

#who-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text,
#who-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text,
#who-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text {
    border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;

    border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
}
```

```html
<span class="menu-item-text">

<span align="center">Headline</span>
</span>
```

But even if it looks fine when I inspect the website, when I check my phone it ignores the margin-bottom and the padding CSS and the borders are too close to my headlines.

This is how I want the borders to look like on :focus.

[image]

This is how I see it at the moment (borders too close and ignore my padding/margins)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I think w3 already has tutorial about this, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Add a bit of padding to the `.mobile-item-text` element. `padding: 5px 0;`

Comment: @MarcHjorth I tried that but it still doesn't appear on phone

Comment: You might have some CSS overridding the padding maybe? @RoziBuber

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the element like this

```css
li.with-padding {
    padding: 5px 0; /* <-- Magic goes here */
}


li {
    border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
    border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
}

li+li { /* Add margin top to second li */
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="with-padding">This is with padding</li>
  <li>This is without padding</li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7krqth8f/11/)